# Setup domain, show other website

Tags: html, redirect, web, dns

I have 1 hosting with domain (for example `portfolio.com`), now I bought second domain without hosting plan (`website.com`).

I want on `website.com` to show content from `portfolio.com/website/index.html`, how should I do this in my redirect/DNS domain setup?

If I try iframe redirect from *OVH* it's works but don't have my meta/title/favicon.

Regards.

Comment: @chriswirz I have 2 domains and 1 hosting plan on OVH with Linux, I need just to show content of HTML/jQuery site (something like _coming soon_ website)

Comment: @chriswirz yes, I have DNS setup panel on `OVH`.

Answer (score 0):

Quick google search brought me to this:

http://help.ovh.com/FreeRedirection

Comment: Actually OVH have only iframe redirect method (I don't have meta, title, favicon, etc.)